# javascript library for creating templates

Tags: javascript, html, templates

Is there any javascript based library like `jquery template`, `jquery.tmpl.js` for creating html templates in order to fill them with json data received from server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at AngularJS, it does what you want and more: http://angularjs.org/

Comment: Yeah, I just realize that I give u only one choice... sorry but it's my favorite one.

Answer (score 1):

For me the simplest is Mustache https://github.com/janl/mustache.js.

Answer (score 0):

there is another simple way ,this might help you
take a look
http://beebole.com/blog/pure/generate-html-from-a-json-without-any-template-but-html-and-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

adds I'll add to the mix.

**ejs** is a good place to start http://embeddedjs.com/ - it is simple to get going with and will get you familiar with the 'handlebars' style syntax that is common to many templating libaries very quickly.

Then **AngularJS** by google - If you need more of a framework with automatic data binding - a 'truer' MVC - http://angularjs.org/

For server side templating on Node js , I like **Dust**, and the LinkedIn team have made a version - [linkedin.github.io/dustjs/.](http://linkedin.github.io/dustjs/) with lots more helpers and template logic